# Get userId from ClaimsIdentity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity, aspnetboilerplate

I using asp.net boilerplate.

I have auth with Bearer Token (JWT).

In the profile method, I need to get userId.

Here is the code of the method

```
 [AbpAuthorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProfileData()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    }
```

Now if I using `identity.` I can get the only a name. How I can get userId from it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

just need to rewrite it like this

`var identity = User.Identity.GetUserId();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public GetClaims (IHttpContextAccessor accessor) // contractor method
{
     var currentUser = accessor.HttpContext.User;
     var userId = currentUser.FindFirst("Id")?.Value;
}
```

Make a class for Claims, inject `IHttpContextAccessor`, and take whatever you want. of course you can inject IHttpContextAccessor on controller but, I do not suggest it.

Comment: We don't need to write separate class for this because we can use `GetUserId()` method

Comment: well, you cen inject httpaccessor on controller as well